# Reverse order of arrows between nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-arrows

I have two nodes in tikz and two arrows connecting them.

However I want the arrow from 01 to 11 to be the top arrow and the arrow from 11 back to 01 on the bottom, i.e. exactly in reverse order compared to how they appear now. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} \node[state](01) {$0,1$};
\node[state,right=of 01] (11) {$1,1$}; 
\draw[every loop] 
(01) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\lambda$} (11) 
(11) edge[bend right, auto=right] node {$\mu$} (01); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correct, you want the arrow from 01 to 11 to be the top arrow and the arrow from 11 back to 01 on the bottom?

If so, turn the rotation order from `right` to `left`.

See my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \node[state](01) {$0,1$};
  \node[state,right=of 01] (11) {$1,1$}; 
  \draw[every loop] 
  (01) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$\lambda$} (11) 
  (11) edge[bend left, auto=left] node {$\mu$} (01) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Sorry if the wording was bad (I will edit my question). Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome.  It's a pleasure, I could help :-)

Comment: No Problem, I don't mind.  As long, as it makes the question clear, everything is fine!

Answer (score 5):

You could use also `->` to indicate where the tip of the arrow goes (even if in your case Jan's solution is better):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture} \node[state](01) {$0,1$};
\node[state,right=of 01] (11) {$1,1$}; 
\draw[every loop] 
(01) edge[bend right, auto=right, <-] node {$\lambda$} (11) 
(11) edge[bend right, auto=right, <-] node {$\mu$} (01); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course the result is the same:

[image]

Comment: I think, your answer is equally correct.  In fact, it was my first try. :-)

Comment: @Jan I've posted it only to show a possible alternative, in this case yours is simpler :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!+1 However, I do not understand why this works: Haven't I already specified that the tip of the arrow goes from (01) to (11), so why does adding <- change the positioning of the arrows?

Comment: @JimmyR. I'm not an expert, I think that with `auto=right` the default is "tip at the starting point", and with `<-` that is reversed. I'll ask in chat to have a correct answer.

Comment: @gernot I think you're an expert: could you answer Jimmy R.'s comment? Thank you!